# TortoiseHg - Setup for Single .NET Developer with Local Copy and Central Repo on Network Share

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, tortoisehg, source-control-explorer

TortoiseHg is sending me mad! No pun intended.

I am a solo .NET developer just trying to achieve good source control e.g. diff and revert.

I wish to have a central repo on a network share e.g. `"\\server\repos\DO I NEED A FOLDER HERE"`

and a local copy e.g. `"... My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Websites\My Website"`

but the quick start guide http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/quick.html is not relevant in my case - **I don't think I want to clone the repository?**

Please could someone outline **the steps and their order** to achieve:

- Local copy
- Central repo on network share (which is backed up regularly)

E.g.

1. Create folder for repository `"\\server\repos\My Website"`
2. Link `".. My Documents\Visual Studio
   2010\Websites\My Website"` to repo
3. Add files / commit files - I'm unsure of the terminology here

or point me in the direction of some idiot-proof documentation.

I chose TortoiseHg because I thought it was modern and simple.

Should I have gone with Source Gear Vault instead?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm far from an expert but I believe that you do want to clone the repository to start with.  You will treat your network share just as any other "server"(bitbucket, etc).  So you clone from the network share to your local machine.  Then any commits you do will be on your local machine.  When ready to send to the network share then just do a push.  The process is exactly the same but instead of some web address you can push to your network share.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the way to do it. The whole thing seems a bit mysterious though. It also seem like a sledge-hammer to crack a nut - wish there was a simpler tool!

Comment: What I would do is create the repository on your `network share`.  Then I would clone it `locally`.  It really is simple.  Once you have mercurial installed, you can just `hg init` any directory and you have a working repository.  Then it's just a matter of setting up the shortcuts to point to the right places so you can do something like `hg push netshare` instead of `hg push \\server\repos" etc.

Comment: Done that. I have my repository in `\\Server\Repos\My Website` and then cloned it to `... My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Websites` then copied my existing files into `... My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Websites\My Website` then `committed` them, then `pushed` them to the central repo. Only time will tell if it is simple. What does it mean to add a file here: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.4/quick.html#add-files I didn't do this step when I set it up - I copied the file in to my working repository and then committed and that was it!

Comment: Copying a file into your repository does not automatically include it in the repository.  In the context of mercurial, adding a file means you are adding it to the repository to be tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm far from an expert but I believe that you do want to clone the repository to start with. You will treat your network share just as any other "server"(bitbucket, etc). So you clone from the network share to your local machine. Then any commits you do will be on your local machine. When ready to send to the network share then just do a push. The process is exactly the same but instead of some web address you can push to your network share.

What I would do is create the repository on your `network share`. Then I would clone it `locally`. It really is simple. Once you have mercurial installed, you can just `hg init` any directory and you have a working repository. Then it's just a matter of setting up the shortcuts to point to the right places so you can do something like `hg push netshare` instead of `hg push \\server\repos` etc.

Also, adding files is not the same as committing.  When you add files you are telling mercurial, "Hey, I want to keep track of changes to this/these files". When you commit, you are telling mercurial, "I've modified my files and I want you to record the changes since the last time I committed".

Comment: Ok so I copied the files into my working repository, should I have then added them? Once I committed and then pushed, the file was sent to the central repository! Surely this would not have happened if the file wasn't added to my local repository first? - Maybe the process of "adding" was hidden somewhere in the Tortoise GUI?

Comment: @ChrisCannon I'm guessing you implicitly did this in TortoiseHG.  See step 4 @ http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.4/quick.html#add-files.

Comment: It all makes sense now - I guess I should have read it properly in the first place thanks! That documentation is seriously lacking screenshots!

Comment: @ChrisCannon: Have you read any basic tutorial on the subject? You seem to be confused with the core concepts of distributed version control. I highly recommend [hg init](http://hginit.com/).

Comment: @ChrisCannon: And, by the way, consider accepting the answer if it helped you.